# relation between cross site request forgery and login

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection

I was wondering if there is any relation between login and cross site request foregry ?
My question is, are there sites that have no login required but still require to be protected from CSRF ? Can you give an example

Answer (score 0):

For CSRF to be effective, your site just needs to be able to act on behalf of someone in a way that doesn't require explicit authentication or validation.

Signed in users via auto-login cookies are the most popular CSRF attacks, but e.g. newsletter subscription forms may be just as vulnerable and can cause people to receive unwanted emails from your system to confirm their subscription.

So to answer your question, although login and CSRF are related, they are not exclusive to each other.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF attacks exploit the authenticity of a client’s requests as an attacking site is able to forge requests that are executed by the client in behalf of the client and thus enjoy the server’s trust in the client’s requests. So the server assumes that any request from a client is intended behavior of the user that controlling the client. CSRF exploits this implicit trust.

At this point it is not necessary that the client is authenticated. Although authenticated users generally have special privileges that attacking sites are aiming for, the main goal of CSRF attacks is sending arbitrary requests in behalf of the user without their knowledge. So target sites can also be any site where you need a different originator than the attacking site (e. g. polls, unique visitors, malicious activities, etc.).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. If I understand correctly your answer, for example in polls where the poll is taken anonymously, the CSRF attack can take place too as the attacker would want to send answers to the poll on my behalf, is this correct ?

Comment: @user502490 Yes, with CSRF you can almost send any request in behalf of the client. The purpose of these requests is left to your imagination.